# AdColony Video advertisment in ios

Tags: adcolony

I Have register a demo app on Adcolony and get appId and zoneId and Implement AdColony in my iOS(7.1 xcode 5.1). [AdColony configureWithAppID:myAppID
                         zoneIDs:@[myZoneID]
                        delegate:self
                         logging:YES];
[

[AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@[myZoneID withDelegate:nil];

Here are the logs:
 AdColony zone ID you provided (myZoneID) is not valid. No ad will display.

Please Give me better Solution as soon as.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are providing an incorrect ID in your code.  Double check both App and Zone IDs and verify that they are correct in your code.

Comment: adcolony video is playing only in full screen, how to play video in some of the portion of screen?

Comment: AdColony videos are required to play full screen, there is not an option to have them play in a portion of the screen.